# GameMaker Studio: fullscreen vs. dialogs

Tags: game-maker

When setting my game to fullscreen, I get problems with dialogs:

- "get_save_filename" opens in the background, and when I close it, the game doesn't react anymore.
- Asking the user a yes/no question exits fullscreen mode and does not enter it again afterwards.
- "window_set_fullscreen" doesn't seem to do anything either...

Can anyone help?

Comment: How are you asking the user a yes/no question?

Comment: I recommend asking the questions directly in the code. Usually dialogs serve to give the developer warnings (whether or not something is happening).

Comment: It helps to get text from the user by manipulating the keyboard_string variable. Set it to a blank string, let the user type stuff, then get the string from the variable. That way you can write your own GUI instead of relying on the default dialog boxes.

Answer (score 0):

By "get_save_filename" dialog, I assume you mean windows dialog to save/load your game somewhere? Here's a few tips:

- You could potentially make a custom file explorer inside the game, which I don't really recommend, but a lot of games do it and it works.
- You can simply save/load files only in the game's directory, so when you are about to save the game, the only thing you ask from the user is a slot number, so each user can have their own save.
- I haven't done gaming in windows for a while, but I assume when you say "Yes/no" questions you mean opening a windows GUI that asks the user a question. From what I remember, when windows has a game fullscreen, it likes to focus on it, so any pop-up would force the game to be minimised, and potentially unload/load assets all over again. If you want your game fullscreen, you don't want to have pop-ups. To be fair, for most games, you don't want GUI pop-ups anyway, as they break immersion with the game.